# prctl PR_SET_NO_NEW_PRIVS failing

Tags: c++, linux

```
if(prctl(PR_SET_NO_NEW_PRIVS, 1) == -1)
    err(0, "PR_SET_NO_NEW_PRIVS failed");
```

I have the above code as the first line in a program. I always err out of the program with:

PR_SET_NO_NEW_PRIVS failed: Invalid argument

I looked up prctl and I'm not sure why it's failing. It takes in the option and then the args. I'm on linux kernel 3.15.6. g++ 4.8.1

How does one set no new privileges?

Solved with:

```
if(prctl(PR_SET_NO_NEW_PRIVS, 1, 0, 0, 0) == -1)
    err(0, "PR_SET_NO_NEW_PRIVS failed");
```

Comment: Sorry. I'm using elementary OS. My kernel is 3.15.6

Comment: The [manual](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/prctl.2.html) says "since Linux 3.5".

Comment: I have a kernel version above 3.5.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Changing to:

```
if(prctl(PR_SET_NO_NEW_PRIVS, 1, 0, 0, 0) == -1)
    err(0, "PR_SET_NO_NEW_PRIVS failed");
```

has solved the issue. Not sure why, but I found it somewhere.